# Installation error while trying to install a gis application using geodjango?

Tags: postgresql, geodjango

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot determine PostGIS version for database "geodatabase". GeoDjango requires at least PostGIS version 1.3. Was the database created from a spatial database template?
```

This is the error I got when I followed this tutorial http://invisibleroads.com/tutorials/geodjango-googlemaps-build.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this error when I didn't properly use the POSTGIS template to create my database (exactly like the error suggests). So did you properly [install PostGIS with the spatial database template](http://invisibleroads.com/tutorials/postgresql-postgis-install.html#prepare-a-spatial-database-template) and did you create your db with -T template_postgis ?

```
createdb -U postgres -T template_postgis -O geouser geodatabase
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I did not follow the steps in the link you mentioned. I followed this: http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ch02.html#id2619431.

I basically applied that to an existing database.

Do you have any suggestions on how I can undo the changes I made so I can apply the one you suggested? I can remove the Geo fields in my models & just rebuild it.

Thanks.