# My PostGIS database looks fine but GeoDjango thinks otherwise... why?

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I'm trying to set up a GeoDjango app to test [an earlier problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486149/) I was having. I've set up a postgresql database, created a new Django project and app, but when I try `./manage.py syncdb` I get this:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot determine PostGIS version for database "django_geotest". GeoDjango requires at least PostGIS version 1.3. Was the database created from a spatial database template?

Which I don't understand as I've previously been through all the installation of GeoDjango's requirements, and created this `django_geotest` database by doing this:

```
$ createdb -T template_postgis django_geotest
```

And it looks like the database is correctly set up:

```
django_geotest=# SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
                                     postgis_full_version                                          
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 POSTGIS="1.5.3" GEOS="3.2.2-CAPI-1.6.2" PROJ="Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009" LIBXML="2.7.3" USE_STATS
(1 row)
```

Describing the database, I get this:

```
django_geotest=# \d                
             List of relations
 Schema |       Name        | Type  | Owner 
--------+-------------------+-------+-------
 public | geography_columns | view  | phil
 public | geometry_columns  | table | phil
 public | spatial_ref_sys   | table | phil
(3 rows)
```

So now I'm stuck as to what to try next... My knowledge of postgresql and its templates etc isn't that great. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem before but I can't figure out how I solved it. I think I tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907672/installation-error-while-trying-to-install-a-gis-application-using-geodjango

Comment: had the same problem with PostgreSQL 9.3 and PostGIS 2.1 installed on OS X 10.9.1 using homebrew, all I had to do was add `POSTGIS_VERSION = ( 2, 1 )` to `settings.py`. It simply couldn't read the setting

Comment: @BenjaminGolder - that solved my problem as well... Suggest it should be the correct answer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same problem with PostgreSQL 9.3 and PostGIS 2.1 installed on OS X 10.9.1 using homebrew.

For this particular issue, you only need to add this line:

```
POSTGIS_VERSION = ( 2, 1 )
```

using the comma separated number for your PostGIS version to `settings.py`.

I'm not sure why, but Django's having trouble reading the version information from PostGIS.

Comment: Going to mark this as the correct answer just because it seems to work for a couple of people; I haven't tried it. Thanks!

Comment: where is settings.py ?

Answer (score 5):

Whenever I've got this error in a similar situation (i.e. when the database seems to be a perfectly valid PostGIS database) it has turned out that there's been an error in `DATABASES` in `settings.py`. It's actually authentication when connecting to the database failing, but it just happens that the first thing that touches the database when starting up my GeoDjango project is the `postgis_lib_version` call from `django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/operations.py`

Comment: This is the best answer.  See ticket  https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24862#ticket

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue a couple months ago. I had to recreate the template_database and the main db again. [From this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#creating-a-spatial-database-template-for-postgis).